# Galera Cluster with MySQL Enterprise?

Tags: mysql, database, cluster-computing, galera, mysql-cluster

Is it possible to install Galera Cluster with MySQL Enterprise?

I tried to check on the web but without result.

IF it's possible, how I'm going to install it?

Comment: If you have Enterprise edition, there is a direct support from oracle team whom can help you.

Comment: Or you could switch to MariaDB Enterprise, which already includes Galera.